# Add Columnheader to Treeview with HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want do add a Columnheader to a Treeview (see below). However, if I add a row to the `ControlTempalte` for the `TreeViewItem`, the Header is shown above each item. How can I add a Headerrow, that just shows once above the whole tree?

I want to show a ColumnHeader like in a DataGrid as shown (white on grey text) in the picture below:

[image]

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding AktuellerDatensatz.Abschnitte}" 
          SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged" Style="{StaticResource StandardTreeview}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>                                
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:BaustelleModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Abschnitte}">

                <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Converter={StaticResource Breite}}"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0 0 1 1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Grau}">
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Grid.Column="1"  BorderThickness="0 0 1 1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Grau}">
                        <Label Content="{Binding Start}"  />
                    </Border>
                    <Border Grid.Column="2"  BorderThickness="0 0 1 1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Grau}">
                        <Label Content="{Binding End}" Grid.Column="2"  />
                    </Border>
                    <Border Grid.Column="3"  BorderThickness="0 0 1 1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Grau}">
                        <Label Content="{Binding Duration}" />
                    </Border>
                    <Border Grid.Column="4"  BorderThickness="0 0 1 1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Grau}">
                        <Label  />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DockPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: I couldn't quite get your requirement completely. Will it be possible for you to share some screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve the requirement is to include `TreeView` inside `DataGrid` instead of doing it reverse. You can refer [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30721/WPF-TreeListView-Control)

With `TreeView`, you can try using `AlternationIndex` to show the headers only for the first item in every level.

```
<Grid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem, Mode=FindAncestor}}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Grid.Style>
```

Remember to set `AlternationCount` to max int value for your `TreeView`.